# Call rotate function in AVL Tree C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I have this code to `rightRotate` a sub tree :

```
void rightRotate(mynode **parentPtr, mynode *child)
{
    // make sure the arguments are valid for a right rotation
    assert(parentPtr != NULL && child != NULL && child->left != NULL);

    // save the three node addresses involved in the rotation
    mynode *F = child;
    mynode *D = F->left;
    mynode *E = D->right;

    // perform the rotation
    *parentPtr = D;
    D->right = F;
    F->left = E;
}
```

Tree struct is :

```
typedef struct tree mynode;   // differences between nametag and type????
struct tree{                    // tree node struct
    int value;
    int key;
    char color;
    struct tree *left;
    struct tree *right;
};
```

My question is : How should I call this function ?

Example : I have a tree and I want to right rotate `son`, since the first argument is a **pointer to pointer to node** and the second a pointer to node how should I write the call?

```
//...some code...
//I have two pointers to nodes : parent and son
rightRotate ( ??? , son)// I didn't get the first argument, what I should write?
//some code...
```

P.S. : This code is from an other post, sorry for this little "spam" but I'm very confused about this simple function and why it works in this way. Can someone explain me a little more?

Comment: Try `rightRotate (& parent, son)` perhaps?

Comment: I was thinking the same but since "parent" is a struct with a value and 2 sub tree, one the left and the other on the right, I don't get the sense of this call. And "parent" is the parent of "son" obviously. I think I should write "parent->right = ..." instead of " *parent =..."

Comment: `parent` is a **pointer**  `mynode*`. `&parent` is a pointer to a pointer `mynode**`. I cannot see where you write `*parent =` so I cannot tell what is right to use at that place, but you cannot just replace `*parent` with `parent->right` and still cave a valid program.